# Профилирование для Python с модулями на C

Tags: python, c, swig

На C написаны модули, которые через swig обертываются кодом python.

Каким образом профилировать из python, так чтобы C - код тоже профилировался ?

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe такое умеет. Правда стоит он прилично